# How to insert bulk records from data Gridview through stored procedure?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to insert multiple records through gridview i am using sql server 2008
and this i a store procedure.

```
create proce
@InvoiceNo int

as 
insert into tbl_school(id) values (@InvoiceNo)
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your question a little bit more? What do you mean by _insert multiple records through gridview_ exactly? You have a data in your gridview and you wanna insert these rows to your `tbl_school` table?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear; however, in the case of a stored procedure that takes one `int` as a parameter and does an `insert`, there is no "bulk" approach here: you just need to call the stored procedure *lots of times* (once per record). If you have flexibility to modify the design, alternative options include:

- passing multiple ids in a string `[n]varchar(max)` that you then pull apart (usually via a "split" udf) to do the insert
- table-valued-parameters
- `SqlBulkCopy` (raw TDS insert, not using a stored procedure)

However: how you get from your gridview to the data-layer is mostly a design and implementation detail for your code.